# removing the first 0 bit value

Tags: python, hash, bit-manipulation, bit

i want to get the binary value from a string, but why if i print the binary value and save it into an array there is always 0 bit get inserted automatically, i know that its from the bitwise operation inside the loop, how can i delete it and get the actual binary value from a string?

this is the code

```
def padding():
    a = "Testing"
    byte_a = a.encode('utf-8')

    print(byte_a)

    print(bin(byte_a[0]))
    print(bin(byte_a[1]))
    print(bin(byte_a[2]))

    i = 0
    x = []


    #byte_a.append(1)

    while True:
        x.insert(i, ((byte_a[i//8]>>(7-(i%8)))&1))
        print(x)


        i+=1
```

and here is the output:

```
b'Testing'
0b1010100
0b1100101
0b1110011
[0]
[0, 1]
[0, 1, 0]
[0, 1, 0, 1]
[0, 1, 0, 1, 0]
[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]
[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0]
[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]
[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]
[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0]
[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]
[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1]
[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0]
[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]
[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]
[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1]
[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1]
[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0]
[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]
[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1]
...
```

as you can see the array had the first value of 0 for every binary.

thanks guys

Comment: The docs for [bin](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#bin) say 'Convert an integer number to a binary string prefixed with “0b”'

Comment: Can you please include the output you want?

Comment: `T` is `84` ` or `0b1010100`. Notice that that's only 7 bits — the eighth bit is `0`. So when you shift by 7 you get `0`. To get the `1` you need to shift by 6 not 7.

Comment: the output that i want is ```T``` = 1010100 not 01010100 @yukashimahuksay

Comment: already tried it and it doesnt work, and raise an error ```negative shift count```            @MarkMeyer